# http 500 error Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My program is sending inviting messages.

if you select tag, will call XmppDServlet.

It's very simple program, but i got http 500 when calling XmppDServlet.

How should i do?

Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

public class XmppDServlet extends HttpServlet {

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException{
    //sendInvite(req,resp);

}
private void sendInvite(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws IOException {
        XMPPService xmpp = XMPPServiceFactory.getXMPPService();

        try {
            //System.out.println(invitee);
          xmpp.sendInvitation(new JID("myaccount@gmail.com"));
          resp.getWriter().print("Chat invite sent to: ");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
          resp.getWriter().print("Unable to send chat invite to " );
        }
      }
```

}

Comment: You need to read the server logs. Pasting the generic "Server Error" message here is completely useless.

Answer (score 1):

Please visit the AppEngine Admin Console for your application. You will see a `Logs` link under the Main section on the left side. Click that and view the Server log. That should give you more information on what caused the 500 Error.